# Mutate from long to wide based on regex match in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that has a number of columns that are prefaced with the following convention "quiz.{number between 1-33}.{variable_name}".  So, for example, "quiz.1.player.trial_counter" or "quiz.33.submitted_answer"

I'm currently grabbing these columns like so:

```
 dat[, c(names(data[, grep('quiz\\.[0-9]*.',  names(dat))]))]
```

Each row is an individual's answers.  I want to have a column that extracts the number from each of the quiz prefaces, and another column describing the variable.

Let's say I have this simplified dataset:

```
dat <- read.table(text="ID quiz.1.player.question quiz.1.player.solution quiz.2.player.question quiz.2.player.solution 
Trx1 A Yes 4 No
Trx1 B Maybe 5 No
Trx2 E No 6 Why
Trx2 B Yes 8 Yes
Trx3 B Definitely 9 Maybe
Trx3 C Yes 8 Yes
Trx5 F No 7 Why
Trx5 D Maybe 0 Ha", header=T)
```

Here's a part of the desired sample output

```
output <- read.table(text="id quiz_number key value
Trx1 1 player.question A
Trx1 1 player.solution Yes
Trx1 2 player.question 4
Trx1 2 player.solution No
Trx2 1 player.question B
", header=T)
```

I have tried various things with `gather` and `separate` and `extract`, but cannot figure out how to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: quite sure `tidyverse` can solve it. here is a `data.table` approach: `library(data.table); melt(setDT(dat), id.vars="ID")[, c("quiz", "num", "player", "key") := tstrsplit(variable, "\\.")][]`

Comment: `dat %>% 
  gather(key = variable, value = value, -ID) %>% 
  separate(variable, into = c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"), sep = "\\.")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for a `tidyverse` solution, we can reshape data from wide to long, and then `separate` entries to reproduce the expected output format.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
    gather(k, value, -ID) %>%
    separate(k, c("quiz_number", "key"), "\\.(?=player)") %>%
    mutate(quiz_number = str_replace(quiz_number, "quiz\\.", ""))
#     ID quiz_number             key      value
#1  Trx1           1 player.question          A
#2  Trx1           1 player.question          B
#3  Trx2           1 player.question          E
#4  Trx2           1 player.question          B
#5  Trx3           1 player.question          B
#6  Trx3           1 player.question          C
#7  Trx5           1 player.question          F
#8  Trx5           1 player.question          D
#9  Trx1           1 player.solution        Yes
#10 Trx1           1 player.solution      Maybe
#11 Trx2           1 player.solution         No
#12 Trx2           1 player.solution        Yes
#13 Trx3           1 player.solution Definitely
#14 Trx3           1 player.solution        Yes
#15 Trx5           1 player.solution         No
#16 Trx5           1 player.solution      Maybe
#17 Trx1           2 player.question          4
#18 Trx1           2 player.question          5
#19 Trx2           2 player.question          6
#20 Trx2           2 player.question          8
#21 Trx3           2 player.question          9
#22 Trx3           2 player.question          8
#23 Trx5           2 player.question          7
#24 Trx5           2 player.question          0
#25 Trx1           2 player.solution         No
#26 Trx1           2 player.solution         No
#27 Trx2           2 player.solution        Why
#28 Trx2           2 player.solution        Yes
#29 Trx3           2 player.solution      Maybe
#30 Trx3           2 player.solution        Yes
#31 Trx5           2 player.solution        Why
#32 Trx5           2 player.solution         Ha
```

Comment: Thanks! Could not figure out how to use regex with separate and mutate